# Using SolrQueryParser to search in Lucene Index or MemoryIndex Java

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I want to build and system using Lucene Indexer (futher as MemoryIndex) to search.
I using Lucene Query Parser is ok, but I want to update to Solr Query parser with complex field and using exist schema.xml

Is any way to convert Lucene Query Parser to Solr Query Parser and search with Lucene Indexer.

This is my program.

```
Analyzer analyzer = new SimpleAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_48);
MemoryIndex index = new MemoryIndex();
index.addField("text", "this is simple text to memory index", analyzer);
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_48, "text", analyzer); // => Want to change to Sorl Query Parser)
float score = index.search(parser.parse("text:memory"));
if (score > 0.0f) {
    System.out.println("it's a match");         
} else {
    System.out.println("no match found");
}
```

Comment: That would basically mean you'd have to instantiate a SolrCore object, acompanied by the relevant config and schema objects, then instantiate a SolrRequest and use that to create the query parser. Have a look at the code for ExtendedDismaxQParser . My question is : what exactly it is that you need from the schema file, as there is surely an easier way to obtain that

Comment: Thank you @omu_negru
I'd have SolrCore but I want to rebuild it.
I want to read some fields in schema to add to query.

Comment: There has to be an easier way to do it . You could just load a SolrSchema file, get the fields and analyzers from there, and pass that map along with a boost map to the lucene q parser

Comment: Thank @omu_negru ! Is there anyway to create SolrCore object and  SolrRequest from Schema.xml and solrconfig.xml by java coding?